# how to get the wanted value from json with php?

Tags: php, json

I have an array like this:

```
$cookie_array = array( 'username' => $row['username'], 'name' => $row['name'], ... );
$encodedcookie = json_encode($cookie_array);
```

And I set this as cookie :

```
setcookie("cookiedata", $encodedcookie, time()+150, '/');
```

I decoded it like that:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookiedata'])){
$decodedcookie = json_decode($_COOKIE['cookiedata'], true);
```

Now what I wanted to do is to get the 'nth' value from this array. ( n = first or second or third... So what I want to explain with 'nth' value is ; first value or second value ...)

For example I want to get the value and define it like this:

```
$blabla = (second value of the array) ;
```

But I dont know how to do that and I didn't find it even in http://www.php.net/ or I couldn't.

Comment: once you decode the json, it's just a php string/array/object/whatever like it was beforehand. Access it like you would any other array/object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$blabla = $decodedcookie['username']; //etc
```

Comment: Thank you very much @AbraCadaver , I don't know Why I haven't tried this :s I'll set your answer as correct one in 10mins. (:

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach to loop through array elements:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($decodedcookie AS $key => $value)
    echo ($count++) . ': ' . $key . ' => ' . $value;
```

Or you can use array_values:

```
$values = array_values($decodedcookie);

echo $values[0];
echo $values[1];
```